# Undefined symbol caml_call_gc after ocamlmklib?

Tags: debian, ocaml

I'm trying to build a library for installation, but I am not sure what this error means:

```
$ ocamlmklib -custom -linkall  ociml.ml -o ociml
$ ocaml
        Objective Caml version 3.12.0

# #load "ociml.cma";;
Cannot load required shared library dllociml.
Reason: ./dllociml.so: ./dllociml.so: undefined symbol: caml_call_gc.
```

I guess I must just be missing some options on the command line? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ocamlmklib without C objects will not generate `dll*.so` at all, and with -custom it will not generate any `*.so` either. So your example is not full/self-containing and so it is hard to guess what is wrong. Look at the existing bindings for examples.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively random suggestion here as I can't reproduce locally, but have you tried `-lcamlrun`? It is supposed to link the OCaml runtime (`-lasmrun` for native code).

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be it. Thanks anyway :-)